# Замена nan на медианное значение "соседей" по списку городов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Дана таблица измерений некого уровня(0,1,2) (с пропусками) по городам и дням:
[image: Исходные данные]
**Задача:**
Заменить пропущенные значения медианой, которая считается по списку городов, близких к региону с пропуском на соответствующую дату.

Столбец `neighbor_id`указывает на `cityID` соседних регионов.

Не до конца понимаю, как заменить значения на медиану по городам. Смог реализовать обычную замену ячейки на число.

```
for i in range(3,9):
for j in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[j,i] == "nan":
        df.iloc[j,i] = 10
```

**Пример датафрейма:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cityID': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 12, 13],
    'City': ["Москва", "Самара", "Волгоград", "Чебокары", "Казань", "Санкт-Петербург", "Архангельск"],
    'neighbor_id': ["2/12", "3/5", "5/7/13", "12" ,"1/2", "1/2/5/7", "1"],
    '2018-12-03': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    '2018-12-04': [0,"nan","nan", 0, 0, 1, 2],
    '2018-12-05': [0, 2,"nan", 2, 1, 1, 1],
    '2018-12-06': [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    '2018-12-07': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,"nan"],
    '2018-12-08': ["nan", 0,"nan", 2,"nan", 1, 1]
    })
```

**Пример датафрейма на выходе:**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'cityID': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 12, 13],
'City': ["Москва", "Самара", "Волгоград", "Чебокары", "Казань", "Санкт-Петербург", "Архангельск"],
'neighbor_id': ["2/12", "3/5", "5/7/13", "12" ,"1/2", "1/2/5/7", "1"],
'2018-12-03': [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
'2018-12-04': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
'2018-12-05': [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
'2018-12-06': [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
'2018-12-07': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
'2018-12-08': [0.5, 0, 1, 2,0.25, 1, 1]
})
```

Comment: Все необходимые данные в таблице есть. В чем случилась проблема?

Comment: Не до конца понимаю, как проитерировать саму матрицу.

Comment: @MaxU, добавил в описание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непростая задача... Не вижу как её можно решить векторизированным способом (из-за специфики `neighbor_id` столбца).

Решение:

сначала заменим строковое значение `nan` реальным `NaN`:

```
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)
```

вспомогательная функция для вычисления медианного значения соседей:

```
def f(df, id_lst, cityID, split_sep='/'):
    ids = list(map(int, id_lst.split(split_sep)))
    t = (df.loc[df['cityID'].isin(ids)]
           .assign(cityID=cityID,
                   City=df.loc[df['cityID']==cityID, 'City'].iloc[0]))
    idx = df.loc[df['cityID']==cityID].index
    return t.groupby(['cityID','City']).median().reset_index().set_index(idx)
```

вспомогательный DataFrame с медианными значениями соседей:

```
r = pd.concat([f(df, r['neighbor_id'], r['cityID']) for i,r in df.iterrows()])

In [130]: r
Out[130]:
   cityID             City  2018-12-03  2018-12-04  2018-12-05  2018-12-06  2018-12-07  2018-12-08
0       1           Москва         1.0         1.0         1.5         1.5         0.5         0.5
1       2           Самара         1.5         0.0         2.0         1.5         0.5         2.0
2       3        Волгоград         1.0         0.0         1.0         1.0         0.0         1.5
3       5         Чебокары         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         0.0         1.0
4       7           Казань         0.5         0.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         0.0
5      12  Санкт-Петербург         1.0         0.0         1.5         1.5         0.5         1.0
6      13      Архангельск         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0         NaN
```

заполним все `NaN` из вспомогательного DF:

```
df.update(r)
```

результат:

```
In [131]: df
Out[131]:
   cityID             City neighbor_id  2018-12-03  2018-12-04  2018-12-05  2018-12-06  2018-12-07  2018-12-08
0       1           Москва        2/12         1.0         1.0         1.5         1.5         0.5         0.5
1       2           Самара         3/5         1.5         0.0         2.0         1.5         0.5         2.0
2       3        Волгоград      5/7/13         1.0         0.0         1.0         1.0         0.0         1.5
3       5         Чебокары          12         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         0.0         1.0
4       7           Казань         1/2         0.5         0.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         0.0
5      12  Санкт-Петербург     1/2/5/7         1.0         0.0         1.5         1.5         0.5         1.0
6      13      Архангельск           1         0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0         1.0
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, я когда-то подобное искал, что-то похожее нашёл на engSO.

Comment: Думаю, что задача бы проще решалась, если id соседних городов были бы в виде списка, да?

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо :)

Comment: @kikudryavtsev, преобразовать `neighbor_id` в список проще простого: `df['neighbor_id'] = df['neighbor_id'].str.split('/').apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))`. Вопрос как получить DF с медианными значениями __векторизированным__ (без цикла) способом

Comment: @MaxU, благодарю за отличный развернутый ответ!